# Can you install a rim joist inside wall joists and does it need extra support?

Tags: renovation

I'm looking at lowering the ceilings of my first floor/floor of my second. Can I nail or bolt the new rim joist to the inside of my wall joists and expect it to be properly supported for a floor? I plan to build a new knee wall from the rafter to the new joists and nail the old ceiling joists to them to prevent twisting of the old rim joist, before cutting out the old floor.

I will be running the final design by an engineer.

Comment: Are you planning on just lowering the ceiling or lowering the second floor?  Imagine it is just the ceiling(which makes life easier) instead of the floor itself.  Ceiling is more decoration, while the floor(joists) are main house support members, and probably would require a decent rebuild of the house from the roof down.

Comment: You haven't provide nearly enough detail for us to answer. For one thing, I can't fathom what "the inside of my wall joists" means. Do you mean _studs_? If so, you're talking about balloon framing. For another, what's the span? You'll need an approved hanging mechanism for the rim. Simple lags probably won't suffice--that's not even allowed for exterior decks in my area. Simpson Strong-tie has hardware for this application, though. I've used it on ICF homes.

Answer (score 1):

You're hiring an engineer to review your plans. His license and career is on the line to ensure you're doing it right and the building doesn't fail.

We're just a bunch of well-intentioned busy-body helpers who have no stake (beyond some personal pride & satisfaction). I'd trust the engineer. Besides, we have very, very few details to go on, he'll be able to review the actual physical structure and ensure your plan will work.

Trust the engineer.

Comment: yes, agreed. As with many framing questions, start with the engineer since OP needs one anyway, or at least a framing carpenter who is local and can assess the specifics of OP's case, not with advice here based on a paragraph of text. It won't -rightfully so- matter what we say if the engineer says otherwise, and it won't make his work easier.